# PHP using explode

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode

I'm trying to explode and separate the results in 2 different arrays

```
One One_x
Two Two_xx
Three Three_xxx
Four Four_xxxx
```

I first want to explode the break line ( \n  ).. 
then explode the space to come up with all **One, Two, Three, Four** in an array
AND **One_x, Two_xx, Three_xxx, Four_xxxx** in a different array

i tried to explode the break line

```
$ex = explode("\n", $numbers);
```

then

```
foreach($ex as $number){
  $ex = explode(" ", $number);
}
```

but it seems a bit confusing to me,

How to solve this ?

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach($ex as $number){
  $tmp = explode(" ", $number);
  $array1[] = $tmp[0];
  $array2[] = $tmp[1];
}
```

Simplest way I think

EDIT: care you set `$ex` in loop ... Not a good idea. Use another var

Answer (score 1):

Instead of runnig explode once or twice, a regex can split up the input at once, and assert the structure at it:

```
 preg_match_all('/
         ^         # line start
         (\w+)     # One, Two, ...
         \s+       # spaces
         (\w+)     # Four_xxxxx
         $         # line end
      /smix',
      $input,
      $array
 );
 print_r($array);
```

Will give you:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => One One_x
        [1] => Two Two_xx
        [2] => Three Three_xxx
        [3] => Four Four_xxxx
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => One
        [1] => Two
        [2] => Three
        [3] => Four
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => One_x
        [1] => Two_xx
        [2] => Three_xxx
        [3] => Four_xxxx
    )
```

One could also use `PREG_SET_ORDER` or even extract the trailing _xxxx (?)numbers.